# Django update an instance of a model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to update an instance of a model in django , however if I try to do this directly I get the Manager not accessible through an instance (as I believe the model manager is a class method).

However what is the best way to update an instance of a model and return the updated instance for use later?

eg

```
address = Address.objects.create(building_name=building_name, postcode=postcode)
address_updated = Address.objects.update(pk=address.id, **defaults)
print(address_updated.street)
```

i.e. the address_updated variable seems a bit superfluous and  pk=address.id doesn't feel quite right.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to update a few fields in that model, this may be the best approach:

```
address = Address.objects.create(building_name=building_name, postcode=postcode)

address.street = "new street"
address.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

If u are looking to update particular variable of a class -

```
address.Column_Name= Value
address.save()
```

You can return same address object with updated value.